# Compare the efficiency or correctness or validity two solutions in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

While solving the below problem from [here](http://dynamiclearningcenter.com/exercises/index-soln.html) I had a different answer from what is given as a sample solution. Since I am quite a newbie to Lisp, I do not know which approach is better. Please share your thoughts.

Question: smallest

Write an iterative function which returns the smallest number in a list:

> (smallest '(4 2 5 8 1 6))
>
> 1

SAMPLE SOLUTION:

```
(defun smallest (lst)
  (let ((smallest (first lst)))
    (dolist (ele (rest lst))
      (if (< ele smallest)
          (setf smallest ele)))
    smallest))`
```

My solution:

```
(defun smallest (lst)
  (let ((sm (car lst)))
    (loop for i in lst when (> sm i) do (setf sm i))
    sm))
```

Also, what could be the difference between `first` and `car`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better:

```
CL-USER 1 > (loop for i in '(4 2 5 8 1 6) minimize i)
1
```

Comment: Thanks Rainer! Wow, this is great. Can you also give explain the difference between `first` and `car`? I can use both on a list.

Comment: Seems like `first` and `car` have the same usage. Both return the first item from a list

Comment: @TeenaGeorge: `first` is an alias for `car`.  Look it up in the hyperspec.